# How to output the variable value with other letters together with fishshell?

Tags: string-interpolation, fish

I want to write a fish shell to change the speed of an audio file.

The shell name is `speed`, I can call it like this:

```
speed 1.mp3 0.7
```

Then I will get a new file `[0.7x] 1.mp3` with changed speed.

But I have a problem with the destination file name:

**speed**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/fish

set source $argv[1]
set ratio $argv[2]

ffmpeg -i $source -filter:a "atempo=$ratio"  "[{$ratio}x] $source"
```

It will output a new file `[{0.7}x] 1.mp3`, which contains unnecessary `{}`. But if I remove it as the `"[$ratiox] $source"`, the `$ratiox` is not correct too.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest is to exit the quotes:

`ffmpeg -i $source -filter:a "atempo=$ratio"  "["$ratio"x] $source"`

Comment: So it's three parts `"["` `$ratio` `"x] $source"` but put together?